# Data.parse is not a constructor?

Tags: javascript

I am using
http://nithinbekal.com/2009/javascript-how-to-create-a-simple-countdown-timer/
But when I run it in firefox I get the error Data.parse is not a constructor.
So what will I need to do to solve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function updateWCTime() {
now      = new Date();
kickoff  = new Date.parse("June 11, 2012 11:30:00");
diff = kickoff - now;

days  = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60*60*24) );
hours = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60*60) );
mins  = Math.floor( diff / (1000*60) );
secs  = Math.floor( diff / 1000 );

dd = days;
hh = hours - days  * 24;
mm = mins  - hours * 60;
ss = secs  - mins  * 60;

document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML =  dd + " days " + hh + " hours " + mm + " minutes " + ss + " seconds";
}
 setInterval(function() { updateWCTime() }, 1000 );
```

Comment: First hit on google 'js date parse' with sample code: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `new` from this line. `Date.parse` is just a method.

```
kickoff  = Date.parse("June 11, 2012 11:30:00");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 'new' keyword before the Date.parse call. Like:

```
kickoff = Date.parse("June 11, 2012 11:30:00");
```

Because you added the new keyword, the parser thought you where creating a new instance of the Date.parse class. Since this method does not support this, you got the error. For the same reason new Date(); does work because Date is an actual class that can be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

You want a **new** Date from the return value of Date.parse

```
new Date(Date.parse("June 11, 2012 11:30:00"))
```

But you can use the constructor to parse the string-

```
new Date("June 11, 2012 11:30:00")
/*  returned value: (Date)
Mon Jun 11 2012 11:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
*/
```