# Converting a datetime string to timestamp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Question in brief:**

What is the easiest way to convert `date-month-year hour(24):minute` to `timestamp`?

*due to more views add clear question on the top, so that no need to go through background & all if need quick help.*

---

**Background :**

I have a simple html table and I used [jquery sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to sort my table columns.

Everything is working fine except a date column which is having following format of data,

```
17-09-2013 10:08
date-month-year hour(24):minute
```

This column is sorting(alphabetically) but not as I expected(date wise). I tried to use a custom parser as follows,

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    id: 'date_column',  // my column ID
    is: function(s) { 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        var timeInMillis = new Date.parse(s);
        return timeInMillis;         
    }, 
    type: 'numeric' 
});
```

**Problem :**
it fails due to `new Date.parse(s)` .

**Question :**
what is the easiest way to convert `date-month-year hour(24):minute` to timestamp? then I can skip `var timeInMillis = new Date.parse(s);` line.

Thanks

**Edited :**

Sorry about the confusion about `milliseconds`, actually it should be the `timestamp` which is a number that represents the current time and date.

Comment: What's wrong with `Date.parse()`, how does it not work?

Comment: You can use `moment.js`: http://momentjs.com/ to convert time to milliseconds

Comment: What exactly do you mean convert to milliseconds? You can't just convert a date to milliseconds. A date is a reference to a specific point in time, milliseconds are a measurement of time from a specific point, if you see my meaning. You can get the number of milliseconds from a specific date, like the number of millis since 17-9-2013, but since you have an entire column of dates, I'm guessing this isn't what you want. Or you can add millis to the current time to get a more exact point, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Pekka error : `TypeError: Date.parse is not a constructor`

Comment: Look at the console when coding. Look at the documentation for [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). Is your date string in a valid format? The docs will tell you.

Comment: @BeanBagKing I need something like timestamp

Comment: @JanithChinthana http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123878/data-parse-is-not-a-constructor

Comment: Just a suggestion: Unless your format is a requirement, I might suggest formatting as [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss] as it's easily sortable without conversion.

Comment: @epascarello my format is not in that list

Comment: @epascarello The problem is that he is using the new keyword.

Comment: @Sumurai8 even I remove that, it is not working

Comment: @Sumurai8 hence my first part of my comment to look at the console and that is half the problem. The other problem is the a valid string does not represent a RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Parsing dates is a pain in JavaScript as there's no extensive native support. However you could do something like the following by relying on the `Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond])` constructor signature of the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

```
var dateString = '17-09-2013 10:08',
    dateTimeParts = dateString.split(' '),
    timeParts = dateTimeParts[1].split(':'),
    dateParts = dateTimeParts[0].split('-'),
    date;

date = new Date(dateParts[2], parseInt(dateParts[1], 10) - 1, dateParts[0], timeParts[0], timeParts[1]);

console.log(date.getTime()); //1379426880000
console.log(date); //Tue Sep 17 2013 10:08:00 GMT-0400
```

You could also use a regular expression with capturing groups to parse the date string in one line.

```
var dateParts = '17-09-2013 10:08'.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)/);

console.log(dateParts); // ["17-09-2013 10:08", "17", "09", "2013", "10", "08"]
```

Comment: what can I do with `dateParts` ?

Comment: @JanithChinthana Well, the regular expression example just shows an alternative way of parsing the date string instead of using multiple `split` calls.

Comment: Link to MDN (not W3)! Nice. +1

Comment: @plalx, it is not working when var dateString = '17-09-2013 10:08:30'; basically not working when there is second counterpart

Answer (score 19):

`Date.parse()` isn't a constructor, its a static method.

So, just use

```
var timeInMillis = Date.parse(s);
```

instead of

```
var timeInMillis = new Date.parse(s);
```

Comment: `Date.parse()` is the best solution. It works in every situation.

Comment: Not true. I have an example with `NaN`

Comment: So what is your example ? @GrávujMiklósHenrich

Answer (score 8):

Seems like the problem is with the date format.

```
 var d = "17-09-2013 10:08",
 dArr = d.split('-'),
 ts = new Date(dArr[1] + "-" + dArr[0] + "-" + dArr[2]).getTime(); // 1379392680000
```

Comment: Just as clarification: `date-month-year hour(24):minute` will be parsed as `month-date-year hour(24):minute`; that's what this fixes.

Comment: @ Sumurai8: OP's question is what's the easiest way to convert the time into ms. What's the other part?

Comment: I try this and it getting `undefined` in `s.split('-')`

Comment: @kadaj He came here in the first place because there was an error in his code. I suppose you are right though. I believe `new Date(...).getTime()` and `Date.parse(...)` do the same thing.

Comment: @Janith Chinthana What does `s` print?

Comment: sorry my bad, it's getting an array `["17", "09", "2013 10:08"]` but then `NaN`

Comment: @kadaj : `17-09-2013 10:08`

Comment: @Janith Chinthana Are you sure you are constructing the date with the array[1] taken first? It's in US time format. Your date is in UK format.

Comment: @plalx No, I the time is not discarded. I am just converting the time from UK format to US format.

Answer (score 1):

For those of us using non-ISO standard date formats, like civilian vernacular 01/01/2001 (mm/dd/YYYY), including time in a 12hour date format with am/pm marks, the following function will return a valid Date object:

```
function convertDate(date) {

    // # valid js Date and time object format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS)
    var dateTimeParts = date.split(' ');

    // # this assumes time format has NO SPACE between time and am/pm marks.
    if (dateTimeParts[1].indexOf(' ') == -1 && dateTimeParts[2] === undefined) {

        var theTime = dateTimeParts[1];

        // # strip out all except numbers and colon
        var ampm = theTime.replace(/[0-9:]/g, '');

        // # strip out all except letters (for AM/PM)
        var time = theTime.replace(/[[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');

        if (ampm == 'pm') {

            time = time.split(':');

            // # if time is 12:00, don't add 12
            if (time[0] == 12) {
                time = parseInt(time[0]) + ':' + time[1] + ':00';
            } else {
                time = parseInt(time[0]) + 12 + ':' + time[1] + ':00';
            }

        } else { // if AM

            time = time.split(':');

            // # if AM is less than 10 o'clock, add leading zero
            if (time[0] < 10) {
                time = '0' + time[0] + ':' + time[1] + ':00';
            } else {
                time = time[0] + ':' + time[1] + ':00';
            }
        }
    }
    // # create a new date object from only the date part
    var dateObj = new Date(dateTimeParts[0]);

    // # add leading zero to date of the month if less than 10
    var dayOfMonth = (dateObj.getDate() < 10 ? ("0" + dateObj.getDate()) : dateObj.getDate());

    // # parse each date object part and put all parts together
    var yearMoDay = dateObj.getFullYear() + '-' + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dayOfMonth;

    // # finally combine re-formatted date and re-formatted time!
    var date = new Date(yearMoDay + 'T' + time);

    return date;
}
```

Usage:

```
date = convertDate('11/15/2016 2:00pm');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just as simple:

```
   var today = new Date(); // Thu Apr 28 2022 21:51:23 GMT+0530
   var todaysTimestamp = new Date().getTime();   // 1651162883379
```