# MySQL DateTime - XAXIS HIGHCHART

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, highcharts

I'm new in this community. Since a few days I'm trying to implement a chart using Highstock. This chart will display the monitoring of temperatures in function of the time.

The values are acquired through PHP and stored in MySQL. I am able to display the temperatures values but not the DateTime in the XAXIS of Highchart.

I am not used with the Javascript and I think my problem could be issued if I find the solution how to convert DateTime into Timestamp in Javascript and displays it as DateTime.

Please find my code below :

```
    <?php

        //Récupération des valeurs stockées dans MySQL
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");       //connexion à la base de données mysql
        mysql_select_db("Chart");                       //connexion à la base de données concernées

?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container">

<script>

<?php
        //récuparation de la colonne "value" dans le tableau "temperature"
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM inside_temp");
        while($ligne = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $inside_temp[] = $ligne[0];
        }
        //récupération de la colonne date dans le tableau date
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM inside_temp");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                //$date_inside[] = $row[0];
                $date_inside_temp[] = strtotime($row[0]) *1000;
                $date_inside_temp[] = date_format($row[0]," Y-m-d H:i:s,");
        }
        //récuparation de la colonne "value" dans le tableau "temperature"
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM outside_temp");
        while($ligne = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $outside_temp[] = $ligne[0];
        }
        //récuparation de la colonne "value" dans le tableau "temperature"
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM thermostat_setpoint");
        while($ligne = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $therm_setpoint[] = $ligne[0];
        }
        //récuparation de la colonne "value" dans le tableau "temperature"
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM consumption");
        while($ligne = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $consumption[] = $ligne[0] / 1000;
        }

?>

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        title: {
                text: 'Consumption & Temperature monitoring'
        },

        subtitle: {
                text: 'Heating experiment - LTU, Summer 2017'
        },

        xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                        //categories: [<?php echo join($date_inside_temp,',') ?>],
                        categories: Date.UTC(<?php echo $date_inside_temp;?>),
                tickInterval: 15,
                labels: {
                        format: '{value:%Y-%b-%e %H:%m}'
                }
        },

        yAxis: {
                title: {
                        text: 'Measured values (°C or kW)'
                        }
        },


        series: [{
                name: 'Wall plug consumption',
                data:[<?php echo join($consumption,',') ?>]

        }, {

                name: 'Inside temperature',
                data: [<?php echo join($inside_temp,',') ?>]

        }, {

                name: 'Thermostat setpoint',
                data:[<?php echo join($therm_setpoint,',') ?>]

        }, {

                name: 'Outside temperature',
                data:[<?php echo join($outside_temp,',') ?>]

     }] //fin de series

    });
```

[The current result in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFxHz.png)

Answer (score 2):

For highcharts you must convert dateTime not only into timestamp, but in timestamp with milliseconds.

When i had such a problem. I converted dateTime to timeStamp with milliseconds in PHP. It is convenient to do in PHP.

**PHP**

```
strtotime({your_dateTime})*1000
```

**MYSQL**
This Query for CONVERT DATETIME to UNIX TIME STAMP

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Apr 15 2012 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p'))*1000
```

But if you want to do conversion in JavaScript ONLY, so:

[converting-a-datetime-string-to-timestamp-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849351/converting-a-datetime-string-to-timestamp-in-javascript)

[how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

---

06.08.2017 - update

**Official docs:**
 [data-from-a-database](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database) How to fetch data from mysql and convert to to highcharts.

Convertation in php sandbox : [php_sand_box](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09da4f247ef9500696c8fae4371d3caf577cb7e1)

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1gbpzeho/

Comment: Yes I did the conversion in PHP as you noticed it in your comment.

However, as you can see it on my code and the attached picture, it doesn't work.

Comment: so you have timestamp in milliseconds and it still doesn't work?? Can you show your timestamp for any item in x-axis&

Comment: You don't need to ceonvert it back to datetime in Js.

Comment: My PHP array after converting datetime into Javascript timestamp looks like that :
Array ( [0] => 1501771394000 [1] => 1501771426000 [2] => 1501771458000 [3] => 1501771490000 [4] => 1501771521000 [5] => 1501771553000 [6]

Comment: so it should work. You don't need Date.UTC();. If still won't work, i'll create jsFiddle with your dates. Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes it should work but it doesn't work. Maybe I made a mistake during the series implementation. Is it right as shown on my code ?

Comment: Yes if you can create a jsFiddle it could very help me. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Ok I understood right now ... Thank you I will try it and feedback !

Comment: Ok @Constantine if I tape the data of the series such as you it is also working. However, if I put the data in one PHP array it doesn't work and nothing is plotted on my chart ...

Comment: I really don't understand because my PHP array ($data) looks like that :

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1501771394000 [1] => 1501771426000 [2] => 1501771458000 [3] ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 25.69 [1] => 25.63 [2] => 25.63 [3] => 25.5) )

And this looks like right ... and then in the highchart I inserted it like that : 

        series: [{
                name: 'Wall plug consumption',
                data:[<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]

Comment: @Sascha E. because data:[<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>] will look like [Array, Array]. Js don't understand such construction. Try to use csv file or table to transfer your data to js in a correct way

Comment: @Sascha E.   Or try smth like [that](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4458e0ebdaa6e08ccb06bb0cbeab242e0c80ab26)

Comment: Your php code doesn't work or it maybe me who don't know how to use it... I will look how I could convert my $data php array into a JS array ... Not easy the javascript !

Comment: Sascha E yeah) i know. it won't work. it was just example, how u can change output of your data. i think that using table is better for your situation. Or use ajax with json. It is not very good to implement such php constructions in js code...

Comment: It is quite difficult, I don't find any solution for my problem

Comment: @SaschaE. Try this [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/374addf631dc630ebaf0d496989e5765b7a010f6) to prepare your php array for JS. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ok thank you. If I try it I need to create a new variable with this function ?

$js_data = prepare_for_js($data) ??

Comment: Thank you for your determination Constantine, but it also doesn't work

Comment: PHP

`strtotime({your_dateTime})*1000` work for me. Thx alot

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Highcharts API on series.data.x](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series%3Cline%3E.data.x)

> x: Number
>
> The x value of the point. For datetime axes, the X value is the timestamp in milliseconds since 1970.

In your code you first convert `DateTime` to milliseconds

```
$date_inside_temp[] = strtotime($row[0]) *1000;
```

then you add a datetime format in your code

```
$date_inside_temp[] = date_format($row[0]," Y-m-d H:i:s,");`.
```

Then you try to convert that back into milliseconds by using Date.UTC() on the array of mixed dateobjects.

```
categories: Date.UTC(<?php echo $date_inside_temp;?>),
```