# Sort Data and Time String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, date, time

I Know there are lot of answers out there to sort `date` and `time`. But in every answer, they sort only `date` or they sort only `time`. I can't find the answer which sorts both date and time string.

Here's the Code I tried:

```
var x = [ '29/09/2020 11:55:56', '04/08/2021 11:57:06', '30/09/2019 15:19:49', '04/08/2021 13:57:06' ]
x.sort((a, b) => new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime()).reverse();
console.log(x)
```

**Output I got:**

```
["04/08/2021 13:57:06", "30/09/2019 15:19:49", "04/08/2021 11:57:06", "29/09/2020 11:55:56"]
```

**Required Output:**

```
["04/08/2021 13:57:06","04/08/2021 11:57:06", "29/09/2020 11:55:56", "30/09/2019 15:19:49", ]
```

I searched whole day. Please Help me with some solutions to fix this.

Comment: I think that this is what you are looking for [How to sort an object array by date property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property)

Comment: Just a hint. Try this `[ new Date('29/09/2020 11:55:56'), new Date('04/08/2021 11:57:06'), new Date('30/09/2019 15:19:49'), new Date('04/08/2021 13:57:06') ]` and you get this `[Invalid Date, Thu Apr 08 2021 11:57:06 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), Invalid Date, Thu Apr 08 2021 13:57:06 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)]` so there's no surprise it doesn't work as you expect since there are 2 invalid dates. All you need to do is to fix the date string format. Your code should work just fine.

Comment: Your problem is using the [built–in parser](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse) to parse an unsupported timestamp format. You can write a simple function to parse the timestamps correctly, then sort as `(a, b) => myParse(a) - myParse(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Date` uses a yyyy/mm/dd format instead of a dd/mm/yyyy format. So all your `Date` objects are `Invalid Date`.

P.S. If you sort but have to reverse the order afterwards, just reverse the subtractions.

Comment: Not all dates are invalid, only the 1st and the 3rd. Although even 2nd and 4th are not  parsed as expected.

Comment: I think it's mostly a miracle that 2/4 even parse to begin with if the format isn't correct.

Comment: Parsing any string other than those supported by ECMA-262 (essentially the formats produced by [*date.toISOString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) and [*date.toString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring)) with the built–in parser is implementation dependent and should be strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Date and time are not separate in the context of a javascript Date object, internally they are just stored as millisecond offsets. But, you can't rely on `Date` parsing strings for you. Write a custom parser for you specific date-time strings and then then simply subtract dates.

There's no need for `reverse()` either, simply switch the subtraction to change direction.

```js
const x = [ '29/09/2020 11:55:56', '04/08/2021 11:57:06', '30/09/2019 15:19:49', '04/08/2021 13:57:06' ];

const parse_date_string = (str) => {
  const [date, time]= str.split(' ');
  const [day, month, year] = date.split('/');
  const [hr, min, sec] = time.split(':');
   
  return [year, (month - 1), day, hr, min, sec].map(Number);
}

x.sort((a, b) => new Date(...parse_date_string(b)) - new Date(...parse_date_string(a)));


console.log(x)
```

Comment: Why not `let [day, month, year, hr, min, sec] = str.split(/\W/)`? Don't forget to subtract 1 from the (calendar) month. :-)

Comment: Fair points, I was going for clarity in the splits for the OP's sake, but the month is def an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

if [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) an option:

```js
var x = [ '29/09/2020 11:55:56', '04/08/2021 11:57:06', '30/09/2019 15:19:49', '04/08/2021 13:57:06' ];
x.sort((a, b) => moment(b,"DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss") - (moment(a,"DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss")));
console.log(x)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very hard task when you try to compare date and time in strings. And would take to much time when executing. Instead i would convert date and times to timestamp format then compare. To convert a date string to a timestamp format i referred to  [the answer on this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849351/converting-a-datetime-string-to-timestamp-in-javascript)

```js
const dates = [ '29/09/2020 11:55:56', '04/08/2021 11:57:06', '30/09/2019 15:19:49', '04/08/2021 13:57:06' ];
dates.sort((date1,date2) => {
    var dateTimeParts = date1.split(' '),
    timeParts = dateTimeParts[1].split(':'),
    dateParts = dateTimeParts[0].split('/'),
    date1;

    date1 = new Date(dateParts[2], parseInt(dateParts[1], 10) - 1, dateParts[0],         timeParts[0], timeParts[1], timeParts[2]);
    
    var dateTimeParts2 = date2.split(' '),
    timeParts2 = dateTimeParts2[1].split(':'),
    dateParts2 = dateTimeParts2[0].split('/'),
    date2;

    date2 = new Date(dateParts2[2], parseInt(dateParts2[1], 10) - 1, dateParts2[0],         timeParts2[0], timeParts2[1], timeParts[2]);
    return date1.getTime() / 1000 - date2.getTime() / 1000
});

console.log(dates);
```

Comment: Consider `let [D,M,Y, H, m, s] = '29/09/2020 11:55:56'.split(/\W/); let d = new Date(Y, M-1, D, H, m, s)`. :-)